# Why had Paul earned a reputation for being against Moses in Acts 21?

Tags: acts, paul, moses

Acts 21:17-26 (NIV):

> 17 When we arrived at Jerusalem, the brothers and sisters received us warmly. 18 The next day Paul and the rest of us went to see James, and all the elders were present. 19 Paul greeted them and reported in detail what God had done among the Gentiles through his ministry.
>
> 20 When they heard this, they praised God. **Then they said to Paul: “You see, brother, how many thousands of Jews have believed, and all of them are zealous for the law. 21 They have been informed that you teach all the Jews who live among the Gentiles to turn away from Moses, telling them not to circumcise their children or live according to our customs**. 22 What shall we do? They will certainly hear that you have come, 23 so do what we tell you. There are four men with us who have made a vow. 24 Take these men, join in their purification rites and pay their expenses, so that they can have their heads shaved. Then everyone will know there is no truth in **these reports about you**, but that you yourself are living in obedience to the law. 25 As for the Gentile believers, we have written to them our decision that they should abstain from food sacrificed to idols, from blood, from the meat of strangled animals and from sexual immorality.”
>
> 26 The next day Paul took the men and purified himself along with them. Then he went to the temple to give notice of the date when the days of purification would end and the offering would be made for each of them.

Why were there reports that Paul was teaching *"all the Jews who live among the Gentiles to turn away from Moses"*? Why had Paul earned such a reputation?

Answer (score 2):

> Acts 21:27 When the seven days were nearly over, some Jews from the province of Asia saw Paul at the temple. They **stirred** up the whole crowd and seized him, 28shouting, “Fellow Israelites, help us! This is the man who teaches everyone everywhere against our people and our law and this place. And besides, he has brought Greeks into the temple and defiled this holy place.” 29(They had previously seen Trophimus the Ephesian in the city with Paul and **assumed** that Paul had brought him into the temple.)

Why were there reports that Paul was teaching "all the Jews who live among the Gentiles to turn away from Moses"?

These were lies. That's their modus operandi. They did the same earlier to Stephen in Acts 6:13

> They produced **false witnesses**, who testified, "This fellow never stops speaking against this holy place and **against the law**.

Why had Paul earned such a reputation?

Jealousy. Paul was successful and they were not.

Acts 17:5

> But other **Jews were jealous**; so they rounded up some bad characters from the marketplace, formed a mob and started a riot in the city. They rushed to Jason's house in search of Paul and Silas in order to bring them out to the crowd.

People have a tendency to believe what they want to believe. Echo chamber. Lack of objectivity.